# Do Greater Angelic Aspect, Legendary Proportions, and Transformation stack?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells

Is there any issues stacking these 3 spells, say a level 17 wizard casting [Time Stop](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/t/time-stop/), then casting [Greater Angelic Aspect](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/a/angelic-aspect/) & [Legendary Proportions](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/l/legendary-proportions/), then lastly casting [Transformation](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/t/transformation/)(could Contingent spell this) to come out of Time Stop as a badass angel of destruction basically.

> **Transformation**
>   School: transmutation; Level sorcerer/wizard 6
>   +4 enhancement bonus to Strength, Dexterity, and Constitution.
>   +4 natural armor bonus to AC
>   +5 competence bonus on Fortitude saves, proficiency with all simple and martial weapons.
>   Base attack bonus equals your character level(including adding additional attacks).
>   You lose your spellcasting ability, use spell activation or spell completion magic items.
>
> **Legendary Proportions**
>   School transmutation; Level sorcerer/wizard 7
>   +6 size bonus to Strength
>   +4 size bonus to Constitution
>   +6 size bonus to natural armor
>   10/adamantine DR.
>   Carrying capacity changes to reflect its new size. The creature’s equipment and weapons(including ammunition & thrown weapons), if any, also increase in size.
>
> **Greater Angelic Aspect**
>   School transmutation[Good]; Level sorcerer/wizard 8
>   low-light vision
>   darkvision 60ft
>   DR 10/evil
>   immunity to acid, cold, and petrification
>   resistance to electricity and fire 10
>   +4 racial bonus on saves against poison
>   Fly 60ft good maneuverability
>   Truespeech
>   Protective aura: +4 deflection bonus to AC & +4 resistance bonus on saving throws against attacks made or effects created by evil creatures to anyone within 20 feet. Otherwise, it functions as a magic circle against evil and a lesser globe of invulnerability, both with a radius of 20 feet.

Mind you, none of these spells are of the polymorph subschool, & only one increases your size so no stacking issue there.

Comment: Hello, Azazel, and welcome to RPG.SE!  This is a great first question.  I've edited it a little bit to bring it more in line with how we format questions here. I added links to the Pathfinder SRD for all of the spells you list, and I changed your title to ask your question in the title, so people know what you're asking before they actually view the question.  You can always re-edit your own question or roll back other people's edits if you feel like an edit has significantly changed what you were trying to ask.

Comment: Using share spells you could cast those spells on your familiar and retain your spell-casting abilities.

Comment: Now I want to make a character that just buffs his Familiar -_- (or just go Summoner like a regular person)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no stacking issues between those spells. None are polymorph spells so they don't override each other. All the bonuses are typed differently so they'll stack.

---

Now, if you're asking if it could be too strong, that's a different story. The three together can make a wizard half decent as a frontliner, but it still won't be good. Take the normal wizard with 10 strength. You end up with 20 strength, full base attack bonus, no feats to help you, and +14 AC (compare to a fighter with +5 Full Plate, who also has his own other bonuses). All in all, you'll still be outshone by a fighter doing his thing, and you won't be able to use your spells (and you blow 3+ high-level spells trying to set it up).

Comment: I see your point comparing it with an actual fighter, though if I play as a Exploiter Wizard, grabbing Armored Caster exploit 3 times & Dimensional Slide. Now can wear +5 full plate like a fighter, with no arcane spell failure in addition to all the above buffs. can also teleport 170ft as part of 5ft steps with Dimensional Slide 11 times a day(at 17th lvl). Add in a Haste, me flying around at 90ft per round, teleporting in & out of combat with say a now large +5 greatsword with 5 attacks per round, and I think I can outshine the fighter, and act like an angelic anime character doing it.

Comment: @Azazel_ Please note that the Armored Caster exploit is third-party publishing (NOT Pathfinder Official Content) and is thus dubious balance. Specifically, it allows you the 13th level ability of the Magus (which only gains access to 6th level spells) for little investment, without a minimum level. Compare with the Arcane Armor training feats, which do less and require a swift action to activate and you'll realize that the 3pp that the exploit comes from should be banned immediately. Also, dimensional Slide must be done as part of a move action, so you can't full-attack with it.

Comment: didn't consider that, probably shouldn't use that then lol.

Comment: Formula: amulet of the mighty +5, Form of Dragon III  ... cast all spells  and then ... Transformation. x7 attacks : (haste) 2 bites full bab, 5 attacks full bab -5. frightful presence,  Immunity to one energy, Fly, Blindsense , darkvision,  Breath weapon. Pretty descend: you can  make good use of all the spells before cast Transformation.

Answer (score 5):

### Yes

As you said, none are from the Polymorph school or uses the same bonus types. Thus, they are all allowed to stack.

With a few notes:

- You gain damage reduction 10/evil and adamantine.
- Transformation effects will be gone before the others, as it lasts only 1 round/level.

Also, do you really want to **prohibit yourself from casting spells or using magic items**? [Giant Form](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/g/giant-form-i/) or [Form of the Dragon](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/f/form-of-the-dragon-i/) will grant similar bonuses and will not force you to discard 17 levels worth of spellcasting power. Granted that some of the bonus won't stack and you might lose 2 str and con, you could gain regeneration and resistance to a few energy types. It is really up to you to consider if gaining +2 str is worth losing the ability to cast spells for nearly two minutes.

Let's take form of the dragon III (available at lv17):

**Form of the Dragon III**: 
+ 10 size bonus to Strength,
+ 8 size bonus to Constitution, 
+ 8 size bonus to natural armor,
DR 10/magic,
frightful presence DC 18+int bonus,
Immunity to one energy type,
Fly 120 (poor),
Blindsense 60,
darkvision 120,
Breath weapon, 
one bite/2 claws/2 wing/1 tail attacks (total of 6 natural attacks).

**Legendary Proportions** :
+6 size bonus to Strength (replaced),
+4 size bonus to Constitution (replaced),
+6 size bonus to natural armor (replaced),
10/adamantine DR, 
Carrying capacity changes to reflect its new size. The creature’s equipment and weapons(including ammunition & thrown weapons), if any, also increase in size.

As you can see, both transformation and legendary proportions can be discarded by a single cast of Form of the Dragon III. And you are still looking like a badass draconic angel. If you don't want to become a draconic creature, you can still use Giant Form with a lower bonus but still humanoid appearance.

Comment: Giant Form would be kind of sufficient replace for a Legendary Proportions, but not Transformation. It also messes up with the "being badass angel of destruction" part, at least in my view.

Comment: Yeah, but "badass angel of destruction" is relative to what type of outsider we are talking about. Some angels look like dogs, others look like chandeliers, while very few have the iconic human-guy-with-wings that we usually associate with the word "angel".

Comment: @ShadowKras yeah, but those that do [are terrifying](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/outsiders/angel/solar/)

Comment: The thing is you still may add Transformation on top of it for better effect. So its still full benefit of Transformation vs spellcasting.

Comment: @annoyingimp i cannot possibly agree that +2 to attack and damage, +2 ac, +2 hit points per level, +5-10 extra BAB justifies **losing the ability to cast 9th level spells**. Sorry.

Comment: You just have to weight the pros and cons of a Belt of Physical Perfection +4 (64,000 gp) vs being able to cast Wish (9th level spell).

Comment: The advantage of Legendary Proportions over Giant Form ll & Form of the Dragon lll in a practical sense mechanically is Legendary Proportions only makes you size large, the other two spells making you size huge can be impractical in a lot of the time depending on where you are. Fluff wise, I like the Angel of destruction look.

Comment: @ShadowKras, the advantage to Transformation is getting base attack bonus 20/15/10/5 granted by the spell for the extra attacks. Also you can still cast Wish, just has to be before or after Transformations duration.

Comment: @Azazel_ the draconic form grants you 6 natural attacks, half being primary attacks. But that's okay if you want to look like a human with wings. But trust me, +10 to attacks does not justify losing spellcasting. 17 rounds is enough for everything to go wrong and you *wish* that you had a quickened dimension door ready.